# Print elements in sorted order from 2 given BSTs

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

This problem is given at [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/all-elements-in-two-binary-search-trees/description/)
It states that given 2 BSTs, return a Java List of type `Integer` that has elements in ascending order.
There are 2 ways I can think of it can be solved

1. Do inorder traversal of each BST and add elements of both traversal into a common `List` and then sort it.
2. Implement a `BST` iterator. Use simple merge technique by instantiating over the 2 trees and moving the iterators. I am pasting my solution for this approach that works(for completeness sake only)

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */

class MyIterator {
    TreeNode root;
    TreeNode iteratorPtr;
    Stack<TreeNode> s;

    public void pushToStack(TreeNode node) {
        while(node!=null) {
            s.push(node);
            node = node.left;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return s.size()>0;
    }

    public int peek() {
        return s.peek().val;
    }

    public int getNext() {
        var retVal = s.pop();
        if(retVal.right!=null) {
            pushToStack(retVal.right);
        }
        return retVal.val;
    }

    public MyIterator(TreeNode root) {
        s = new Stack<>();
        this.root = root;
        pushToStack(root);
    }
}

class Solution {
    public List<Integer> getAllElements(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2) {
        var iterator1 = new MyIterator(root1);
        var iterator2 = new MyIterator(root2);

        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        while(iterator1.hasNext() && iterator2.hasNext()) {
            if(iterator1.peek()<iterator2.peek()) {
                lst.add(iterator1.getNext());
            } else {
                lst.add(iterator2.getNext());
            }
        }
        while(iterator1.hasNext()) {
                lst.add(iterator1.getNext());
        }
        while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
                lst.add(iterator2.getNext());
        }
        return lst;
    }
}
```

**How do I solve this using recursion that recurses over both Trees and the method is intelligent enough to increment the right inorder pointers in single recursion manipulating both pointers?**
Basically say a method like `recurse(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2, List<Integer> lst)`. This method must be able to compare the 2 values, then decide how to recurse. But I am not sure how to come up with it. Because with single tree, the we rely on recursion to give us the benefit of stack that can achieve inorder of a single tree

Comment: No that is not possible.

Comment: You can make do with one iterator traversing the other tree, or a recursive procedure using extended state, whether using parameter passing or instance member access. (say, min and max to enlist)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot recurse over the two trees simultaneously here as you need to traverse the two trees independently (each time you return from a recursive call you effectively move back up *both* trees). The simplest solution I can see is to use a stack-based solution, albeit with two stacks:

```
public static List<Integer> getAllElements(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2) {
    final List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();

    final Deque<TreeNode> stack1 = new ArrayDeque<>();
    final Deque<TreeNode> stack2 = new ArrayDeque<>();

    TreeNode node1 = root1;
    TreeNode node2 = root2;

    while (node1 != null || !stack1.isEmpty() || node2 != null || !stack2.isEmpty()) {
        while (node1 != null) {
            stack1.push(node1);
            node1 = node1.left;
        }

        while (node2 != null) {
            stack2.push(node2);
            node2 = node2.left;
        }

        if (stack2.isEmpty() || (!stack1.isEmpty() && stack1.peek().val <= stack2.peek().val)) {
            node1 = stack1.pop();
            l.add(node1.val);
            node1 = node1.right;
        } else {
            node2 = stack2.pop();
            l.add(node2.val);
            node2 = node2.right;
        }
    }

    return l;
}
```